# Populating images on a Keynote file using Javascript for Automation (JXA)

Tags: javascript, javascript-automation, keynote

I would like to populate a keynote presentation with images that I have stored in my home directory.

Each image should go to one slide. I've looked a lot on the internet but I've only an example which doesn't work for me.

```
let app = Application('Keynote')

app.documents[0].currentSlide.images.push(app.Image({
  file: Path("/path/to/image.jpg")
}))
```

This is the script I've done up to now.

```
app = Application('Keynote')
app.includeStandardAdditions = true


doc = app.Document({
    documentTheme: app.themes['White']
});
app.documents.push(doc)

// Create and append a new "Title & Bullets" slide.
slide = app.Slide({
    baseSlide: doc.masterSlides['Title & Bullets']
});

doc.slides.push(slide);

slide.defaultTitleItem().objectText="Hello"

slide.defaultBodyItem().objectText="Test1\ntest2"

doc.slides.push(slide);

slide.images.push(app.Image({file: Path("~/a.jpg")}))
```

The script above creates the presentation correctly and adds the text as it should, but it fails to add the image.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Pedro

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue Pedro, did you ever manage to insert an image to keynote with javascript (or AppleScript for that matter?)

Comment: @Aqueum Hi. Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately I wasn't able to do it. I moved away from JXA for this purpose.Cheers, Pedro

Comment: Thanks @Pedro, we ended up using python-pptx

Comment: @Aqueum You're very welcome. Cheers, Pedro

Comment: Have you tried to switch last 2 lines? I.e. at first you push image to slide. And then you push slide to document.